# SwiftUI - Add to favorite list then display View

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, favorites

Let's suppose i have a view with a list of books and by clicking on each one of them they display a view with the rusume of the book (the data of books title and text resume are loaded from a json file). 
Then i have another view that displays favorites books but at first it's empty

I want to add to my favorite view only the titles of the books that I want by clicking on a button near the title of each book in the list. 
Then when I'm on the favorite view, if I click on a saved title I want to jump directly to the resume text view of that book.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var bookData = BooksData()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< bookData.books.count) { num in
                NavigationLink(destination: (
                // Resume text view of current book
                )) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(bookData.books[num].title)")

                        Spacer()

                        Button(action: {
                            // Add to Favorite List
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "heart")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct FavoriteView: View {
var body: someView {
    // Display saved titles and send to Resume View when tapped
}
}
```

What are the steps in order to make a connection of this type by saving my favorites even after closing the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I cannot provide some code because my actual app is different from the example but the idea is the same. If I paste my code here it wouldn't be understandable. I just need to know what are the steps to achieve my objective

Comment: That’s exactly why there are instructions on how to supply a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: I tried to make it clear now, hope someone can help me :)